# Microsoft Visual Foxpro DLL call in Node or Java

Tags: javascript, java, visual-foxpro

I'm new to Visual Foxpro. I want to build a dynamic link library (dll) file using Visual Foxpro for calling the Visual Foxpro function in Node or Java to build rest API.

I tried it with Node and Java. I had an issue when I used the Foxpro dll file. So I created a C# dll, and got the same issue. So then I read a document which said to use **> [DLLEXPORT]** tag above the function which I want to call in another native language.

I built a 32-bit and 64-bit dll to use with my native language code. It was successful. My question is that I want to build both 32-bit and 64-bit dll files with Visual Foxpro to use with Node.js code.

This is my C# code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using net.r_eg.DllExport;
    
    namespace FDLL
    {
        public  class First
        {
            [DllExport]
            public static String getData()
            {
                Console.Write("Call Function Successfully!");
                return "HI Welcome";
            }
        }
        [DllExport]
        public static String getData1(String a)
        {
            Console.Write("Call Function Successfully!");
            return "HI Welcome"+ a;
        }
    }
```

If I did not use  **`[DllExport]`** tag, getData could not be invoked in my Node or java code.

This is my Node.js code:

```
const ffi = require("@saleae/ffi");

const libm = ffi.Library("./FDLL", {
    getData: ["string", []],
    getData1: ["string", ["string"]]
});
```

It works fine, but my Foxpro dll is not working.

This is my Visual Foxpro code:

[image: screenshot of VFP code]

This is the JavaScript code for accessing my Foxpro `GetDrugsJSON()` function

```
 var libm1 = ffi.Library("./cw/comdemo", {
         GetDrugsJSON: ["String", []],
     });
    console.log(libm1.GetDrugsJSON())
```

But I cannot invoke `GetDrugsJSON()` function with JavaScript code.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi Ramesh. It is possible to call a VFP COM through node.js
You will need to install winax module. Please search it on npm website.

Comment: I had given a session on this during Oct-2020 Virtual Foxfest. It is available on youtube under "geekgatherings" channel. Just like your case, our mammoth ERP is written in VFP10 (also known as Visual Foxpro Advanced) and our company is not yet ready to make the switch to another ERP. So I exposed the ERP data via VFPA COM APIs with frontend (mobile and pwa apps) written with Quasar (Vue3) platform. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, you cannot build 32 and 64 bits DLL with VFP.

Also a DLL is a broad term (while it is short for Dynamic Link Library, there are different DLLs).

You are saying "in Node or Java to build rest API". For creating REST API you wouldn't want to use VFP. Use something else, be it C#, Go, ...

With other languages too, if you are accessing VFP data via VFPOLEDB then it needs to be 32 bits.

Comment: Yes , But i currently working on 30 years old project and it was used VFP. and there are large condition in those VFP function. So i just want to invoke them via dll to make rest api to make Web and mobile app. and i 'm new to .net and .net core. is there any option to invoke the VFP function in java or Node. and Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @RameshChathuranga, I don't know of a direct way. Indirectly however, you could create REST API using C# (ASP.Net MVC) that would utilize those DLLs. (In my case, I started like that and then ended up writing all in pure C# - COM is evil).